# Excel link or VBA macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, links

I have a workbook that currently links to 40 other workbooks using the normal cell formula linking to another workbook. This makes opening the master workbook extremely slow. Will it be any quicker if I write vba code to read the data from the other workbooks?

Comment: I think close to no, if source workboors are simple static data tables, and yes if they contains a lot of calculations. Sorry, I cannot prove this.

Comment: Use Power Query.

Comment: Suggest you try it and see.

Answer (score 3):

I think it could, but it depends on when/how the data from these linked files is required.

If you need the data from the linked files right away upon opening the spreadsheet at best you may get a small increase by inspecting the source files and optimizing them.

If some of this data is not needed until later, or based on ad-hoc needs or timing, you may link these files using a button or control to retrieve this data only when required. By removing these data sources from the links and retrieving them "on demand" you may end up speeding up the initial load time of the spreadsheet.

Basically, inspect each source file, ask yourself when the data from that file is required in the main sheet, and then choose how to link it based on this.

Answer (score 1):

In theory and in practice yes, there is a way to load book on demand, yet the code is long. This could be done on such actions as changing sheets, or simply hitting a button so it can refresh some part of a sheet.

But the way you present this problem, looks more fashioned to a central data base and a view excel sheet. Which in turns makes you really think about using Microsoft Access and work with real dbs. Your are borderline about to make a jump to a more efficient way to work and read data, but it depends on the structure of it.

If your sheet, or sheets in this case, has a lot of format and "volatile calculations"(as in `=sum("b3:b6")` then they will tax big time your equipment. Try to store everything as formatless value.